# Sampling from low density regions

Tags: sampling, density-function

Assume I have some distribution $p(x)$ that is constrained to some closed and bounded region in $R^n$. I would like to have some way of sampling from some distribution $q(x)$ such that $q(x)$ is high in regions where $p(x)$ is low and the inverse is true. Any ideas on how to do this?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: How about the normalization of $max(p)-p$?

Comment: @frank that would work but how would you sample from it?

Comment: There are many techniques. Which to choose depends on your situation. For an introduction to classical sampling methods, see e.g. [Bishop](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2006/01/Bishop-Pattern-Recognition-and-Machine-Learning-2006.pdf).